# Closed set in metric space

Tags: functional-analysis

In $C\left( {\left[ {0,1} \right]} \right)$, we define metric 
$$d\left( {f,g} \right) = \mathop {\max }\limits_{t \in \left[ {0,1} \right]} t\left| {f\left( t \right) - g\left( t \right)} \right|.$$
We define $A = \left\{ {f \in C\left( {\left[ {0,1} \right]} \right):f\left( 0 \right) = f\left( 1 \right)} \right\}$. Is $A$ an open or closed set in $C\left( {\left[ {0,1} \right]} \right)$ with metric $d$??

Comment: Yes, it is definitely either open or closed.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path: it's certainly not the case that every set must be either open or closed.

Comment: Hint: considering $f(t)=0$ and $g(x) = \epsilon t$ should enable you to answer one of your questions.

Comment: @GregMartin I agree, and it's all the more the case for vector subspaces, since vector subspaces are open only if they are closed.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path: This claim is more than wrong. Subspaces are open if and only if they equal the entire space!

Comment: @gerw Where are you negating the fact that they are open only if they are closed?

Comment: @SaucyO'Path: Because this "fact" is plainly wrong! Do you have a good reason to believe that subspaces are open iff they are closed?

Comment: "only if" is not the same as "if and only if". @gerw

Comment: If a subspace is open, then it is closed.  Some people were confused by "only if".

Comment: @SaucyO'Path: Oh, I always read "if and only if". Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**$A$ is not open**

Consider the sequence $(f_n)$ defined by
$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
1 -nx & 0 \le x \le 1/n\\
0 & 1/n \le x \le 1
\end{cases}$$

It is a sequence of continuous functions. You'll verify that $d(f_n,0) = 1/4n \to 0$, $0 \in A$ and $f_n \notin A$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Therefore $A$ can't be open.

**$A$ is not closed in $\mathcal C([0,1])$**

Consider the sequence:

$$g_n(x)=\begin{cases}
1 -nx & 0 \le x \le 1/n\\
\frac{n}{n-1}\left(x-\frac{1}{n}\right) & 1/n \le x \le 1
\end{cases}$$

of elements of $A$. It converges in $\mathcal C([0,1])$ to the identity map $i$ which does not belong to $A$. Hence $A$ is not close.

Comment: I would appreciate explaining one aspect connected with the reason why the set $A$ is not open. I understand every step, but the idea isn't clear for me. We have shown that $f_n$ (which are not in the set $A$) converges to $0$ in our metric and its limit belongs to $A$. Intuitively it shouldn't be possible of course, but my main question is: how is this associated with checking if $A$ is an open set? I can't see here relationship with a definition of open set. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $A$ would be open, as $0 \in A$, there would be an open ball centered on $0$ and included in $A$. This can't be as $f_n \notin A$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: Yes, of course. Now everything is clear for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The part on the closedness of $A$ is not correct. The question asks if $A$ is a closed subset of the continuous functions, so giving a sequence that converges to a non-continuous function cannot answer that.

Comment: @MaoWao You're right and $A$ is in fact closed in $\mathcal C([0,1])$. Response updated.

Comment: But does convergence with respect to $d$ imply convergence at $0$? With the factor $t$ in the definition of $d$, this seems at least not clear.

Comment: Not good to come back after two years and two quickly on an answer. My initial answer is correct as the identity map is continuous. Your initial comment is wrong.

Comment: The initial version was correct, but then you somehow changed it to "converging to a non-continuous map". Anyway, everything is back to the correct version now, so that's fine.